# Question about eventually periodic and periodic points.

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

As a part of the course on dynamical systems, I have to read and understand a paper by Li and Yorke, [Period three implies chaos](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.329.5038&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and then present it in my class. In this paper a point $p$ is a periodic point with period $n$ if $p\in J$ and $F^n(p)=p$ where $n$ is the least such positive integer.

And, a point $q$ is eventually periodic if $p=F^m(q)$ is periodic for some $m\in \Bbb{Z^+}$.

Now it is written in there that since F need not be one-to-one, there may be points which are eventually periodic but are not periodic.

So here arise my questions-

1. What is a good example of "there may be points which are eventually periodic but are not periodic" for some many one function ?
2. Are there any eventually periodic points which are also periodic (for both one-one and many one function case)?
3. What if $F$ is one-one?

For the first question, if I consider $F(x)=x-x^2$ on real line which is not one-one, then $0$ is periodic of period one, and $1$ is eventually periodic for $m=1\ \text{as}\ F(1)=0$ which is periodic with period one. But $1$ itself is not periodic as we can see. This example is trivial as I considered periodic point of order one, so are there any better examples (or a class of examples) for cases like periodic points of order $2,3, \dots , n$ for all natural numbers.

For second question, if there is a function in which  $f(0)= 1, f(1)=2, f(2)=0$ , we have $0$ as a periodic point with period $3$ and $1$ is eventually periodic with $m=2$. Is this correct way to think about it?

For third, I found a proof that says if $F$ is one one, it cannot have eventually periodic points, but shouldn't be every periodic point eventually periodic trivially. So when we define eventually periodic, should we mention them as not periodic. 
Also if you can give any more insights into these concepts it will be great. I am just starting on this topic.

Answer (score 3):

We should either specify in the definition that eventually periodic points must not be periodic, or else deal with the fact that all periodic points are also eventually periodic. (If $p$ is periodic, then $F^n(p) = p$ for some $n>0$, so $F^n(p)$ is a periodic point, so $p$ is eventually periodic.)

I assume that the proof that a one-to-one $F$ has no eventually periodic points takes the first option. If we do the same, then the answer to your question 2 is that no eventually periodic point is periodic, of course. Otherwise, all periodic points are examples.

We can get a nontrivial example for question 1 with $F(x) = 1-x^2$. Then $F(0) = 1$ and $F(1) = 0$, so both $0$ and $1$ are periodic with period $2$. We also have $F(-1) = 0$, so $-1$ is eventually periodic: after one step, it joins the cycle, and then it stays there. We also have $F(\sqrt2) = -1$ and $F(-1) = 0$, so $\sqrt2$ is also eventually periodic (it just takes $2$ steps to reach a periodic point), and so on.